# DocumentDb : nesting objects vs factoring against common properties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Let's say we have these documents :

```js
Client :
{ "Third":{"BirthDate":"1987-09-06T00:00:00","DeathDate":null},
  "Profession":{"StartDate":"2002-1201T00:00:00","EndDate":null},
  "Coordinates":{"HomePhone":"*********","MobilePhone":"*********","ProfessionalPhone":null,"Email":"*******"}}

Spouse :
{ "Third":{"BirthDate":"1987-09-06T00:00:00","DeathDate":null},
  "Coordinates":{"HomePhone":"*********","MobilePhone":"*********","ProfessionalPhone":null,"Email":"*******"}}
```

We have 2 very similar objects. Regarding business, it makes sense for us to nest the 'Spouse' object in the 'Client' object. On the other hand, they share common properties. As DocumentDb indexes every property, I'd like to know if there is any advantage to nest one object in the other, vs inserting 2 documents into the collection with an aggregation key. Will a single index run on 'Client' and 'Spouse' common properties ?

Regarding DocumentDb indexing strategies, is it possible (aka, a risk, a bad thing) to have duplicate indexes, or am I completely wrong ? I have found this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing/) on msdn but it does not help.

**What are the impacts on indexes of nesting objects, vs, factoring against common properties ?**

Comment: This is a fairly broad question with no single right answer, as there are many considerations for document modeling (referencing, embedding, normalizing, denormalizing, combinations of all of those, etc.). Then things like bounded vs unbounded nested-arrays and more... This makes for a great discussion / presentation, but really not something easily answered objectively here.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I have been on your blog, a lot of interesting things here ! :-)